# How to add username with email and password in realtime while user creation?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

While user creation I want to create a custom username for that particular UID and check if the username is used by someone else.

I have tried using `updateProfile()` but I think it's not working.

```
      btnSignup.addEventListener('click', e => {
            const email = signupEmail.value;
            const pass = signupPassword.value;
            const userName = signupUsername.value;
              firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass)
              .then(function () {
                user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
                user.sendEmailVerification();
              })
              .then(function () {
                user.updateProfile({
                  username: userName
                });
              })
              .catch(function(error) {
                console.log(error.message);
              });
              alert('Validation link was sent to ' + email + '.');
      });
```

While registration I just want the username to be assigned to that particular UID and nothing else(profile pic and all).

Comment: Are you using that code on the frontend or backend?

Comment: I am using that code on the frontend.

Comment: you need to pass user to the then call back, you are not doing that hence it;s not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let user;
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass)
              .then(function () {
                user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
                user.sendEmailVerification();
              })
              .then(function () {
                user.updateProfile({
                  username: userName
                });
              })
              .catch(function(error) {
                console.log(error.message);
              });
```

This may help you.